# How to override function in python for objects

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, virtual-functions

I have a project in python 2.7.
The user will give me a function implementation and I will override my base class function with the user's implementation. There will be many users.

```
class Base():

    def my_fun(self,x,y,z):
        ## to be overriden by user's function
```

---

```
from user_defined import user_function

base = Base()
base.my_fun = user_function
```

I am new to python, how to implement something like virtual function in python, or what is the best way to accomplish this. Also to override that function I will have to import all the files in which the user has defined their function. How can this be done inside a for loop?

Comment: "*I have a project in python 2.7*" -- why? Python 2.7 [reached EOL at the start of 2020](https://endoflife.date/python). Strongly consider upgrading to Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Some ways for binding method with instance, chose one, and loop the functions, and bind them.

```
base.my_fun = user_function.__get__(base)
```

2nd way:

```
import types
base.my_fun = types.MethodType(user_function, base)
```

3rd way:

```
from functools import partial
base.my_fun = partial(user_function, base)
```

last way:

```
def bind(instance, method):
    def binding_scope_fn(*args, **kwargs):
        return method(instance, *args, **kwargs)
    return binding_scope_fn

base.my_fun = bind(base, user_function)
```

Comment: How can I import functions in a loop? I will be given a path to the directory where all the files with the user's implementation of the function are given.

Comment: I think you need a map, which presents the relationship of base function and the user functions, then loop the map's items.